i'm getting no module named 'scikit-posthocs' when importing scikit_posthocs
i can't import scikit_posthocs even i installed the package.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scikit_posthocs'.
Here as you can see in the terminal the library was successfully installed.

NB : I'm using python Python 3.7.0 in vs code in windows 10, not Anaconda or another environment.
edit:




Try to purge cache "pip cache purge" and remove and reinstall scikit-posthocs

My question might be silly... but it doesn’t hurt to ask: did you select/activate your environment before running the project? If you installed it correctly, maybe you're not running it from the environment where you installed it. Also, did you activate the environment before installing?
If yes, please provide more details. For example, share a model of your project structure, a screenshot of your VS Code, and the prompt of your terminal, not just the output.

@SeverinPappadeux the  "pip cache purge" didn't work for me.

I would guess that you have two different installations of python on your computer, and the module is installed for one of them but not the other.  Please edit the question and show us the output of this command pip show scikit-posthocs, and also the output of this code import sys; print(sys.path)

Yes as you said i had two version of python . But i still don't know why i have the envirenement is working with python 3.12.4 and it the vs code terminal 3.7 ?

It looks like your pip command is using Python 3.7, but you have configured VS Code to use Python 3.12.

Also, are you sure you're using VS Code?  Seeing Cell In[11] in that screenshot makes me think it is actually Jupyter Notebook, not VS Code.

@JohnGordon yes actually i'm using Jupyter Notebook in VS code

The solution is to adjust all of your tools (pip, command-line interpreter, vs code, jupyter notebook, and whatever else) to use the same python.

and how to do that please ? @JohnGordon

For the command-line programs, you would adjust your system path and/or command aliases and/or use a virtual environment.  For VS Code, I believe the command to choose a python version is ctrl-shift-P.

@JohnGordon thank you but yes i've already did that but still doesn't work. it stuck with python 3.7
